# Выборка данных из XML (SAX Parser), Java

Tags: java, xml, sax

С помощью **SAX** перебираю *XML-файл*:

```
<Главный_узел атрибутХ="значение" атрибутУ="значение">
  <Дочерний_узел>
    <Дочерний_узел атрибутZ="textBox1" атрибутХХ="это значение надо сравнить с атрибутом атрибутСравнить что бы достать Путь_к_файлу в Дочерний_узел2"/>
    <Дочерний_узел атрибутХ="textBox1" атрибутХХ="это значение надо сравнить с атрибутом атрибутСравнить что бы достать Путь_к_файлу в Дочерний_узел2"/>
  </Дочерний_узел>
  <Дочерний_узел2>
    <B Путь_к_файлу="545.jpg"  атрибутСравнить="5550" />
    <B Путь_к_файлу="5545.jpg" атрибутСравнить="5550" />
  </Дочерний_узел2>
</Главный_узел>
```

Два дочерних узла, информация из одного файла. Мне необходимо взять один атрибут из `Дочерний_узел` (если `атрибутZ` == `textBox1`) и сравнить его с атрибутом `Дочерний_узел2`: если `true`, то я должен вытащить путь к файлу, который записан во втором дочернем узле `Дочерний_узел2`.

Немного не улавливаю суть. Надеюсь на помощь.

Comment: Обозначьте более точно вопрос.
Сейчас все выглядит так, что, по сути, нужно сохранить данные из <Дочерний_узел> (например, в мапу) и использовать эти сохраненные данные при проходе <Дочерний_узел2>

Comment: Что то вроде того, только эти данные их первого узла надо сравнить со значением атрибутов второго узла. Если они схожи то надо достать путь к файлу.

Comment: Ну тогда и используйте этот подход.
При старте разбора <Дочерний_узел> очищайте вашу мапу с нужными вам  данными, при разборе <Дочерний_узел2> - доставайте из неё все, что вам необходимо.
Но не забывайте - это будет актуально при условии, что в <Главный_узел> больше нет дочерних узлов, необходимых для аналогичной проверки. Иначе нужно будет немного исправлять алгоритм.

Comment: вот нашел пример http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24113529/how-to-get-elements-value-from-xml-using-sax-parser-in-startelement
надеюсь поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Можно поискать **Путь_к_файлу** так

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

public class SAXPars extends DefaultHandler {
    public static String атрибутХХ = null;
    public static String Путь_к_файлу = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
        xml.append("<Главный_узел атрибутХ='значение' атрибутУ='значение'>");
        xml.append("  <Дочерний_узел>");
        xml.append("    <Дочерний_узел атрибутZ='textBox1' атрибутХХ='5551'/>");
        xml.append("    <Дочерний_узел атрибутХ='textBox1' атрибутХХ='5550'/>");
        xml.append("  </Дочерний_узел>");
        xml.append("  <Дочерний_узел2>");
        xml.append("    <B Путь_к_файлу='545.jpg'  атрибутСравнить='5550' />");
        xml.append("    <B Путь_к_файлу='5545.jpg' атрибутСравнить='5551' />");
        xml.append("  </Дочерний_узел2>");
        xml.append("</Главный_узел>");
        SAXParserFactory.newInstance()
                        .newSAXParser()
                        .parse(
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                xml.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")
                            ),
                            new SAXPars()
                        );
        System.out.println(
            String.format(
                "[атрибутХХ=%s, Путь_к_файлу=%s]",
                атрибутХХ,
                Путь_к_файлу
            )
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {
        if ("Дочерний_узел".equals(qName) && "textBox1".equals(attrs.getValue("атрибутZ"))) {
            атрибутХХ = attrs.getValue("атрибутХХ");
        } else if ("B".equals(qName) && атрибутХХ != null && атрибутХХ.equals(attrs.getValue("атрибутСравнить"))) {
            Путь_к_файлу = attrs.getValue("Путь_к_файлу");
        }
    }

}
```

*результат:* [атрибутХХ=5551, Путь_к_файлу=5545.jpg]